# Automated input generator for black-box testing

Tags: testing, input, user-input, testcase, black-box-testing

I am a newbie for software testing. I want to know, is there any open source tool for automated test case generator black-box testing.

I found this tool [KLEE: unassisted and automatic generation of high-coverage tests for complex systems programs](http://klee.llvm.org/), but to use this tool I need to do some code instrumentation. Is there any way I can generate automated testcases without code instrumentation as I don't have access to the source code.

Answer (score 0):

KLEE does work with programs without modification. You can have it generate symbolic command line inputs as well as symbolic input files. Here are some example commands that can be used for this purpose:

> -sym-arg               - Replace by a symbolic argument with length N
>
> -sym-args    - Replace by at least MIN arguments and at most
>                                 MAX arguments, each with maximum length N
>
> -sym-files        - Make stdin and up to NUM symbolic files, each
>                                 with maximum size N.
>
> -sym-stdout               - Make stdout symbolic.

Examples can be found in the tutorials on KLEE's website.